# Export to excel help in GridView

Tags: gridview, asp.net-2.0, export-to-excel

I have implement functionality for exporting data from gridview to excel sheet in .net application.Rendered output of gridview on page is given below:

[image]

don't bother about header and footer as i am showing a litle part of gridview.
and data exported in excel-sheet is:

[image]

Code in aspx page is for particular currency column in grid-view is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="lblBoldTextLeftPadding clsGridHeaderDashboard" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        £<%# Eval("Value") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="lblNormalTextLeftPadding" Width="10%" VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As you can see in excel-sheet the currency column value is [ Â£100 ] but in grid-view  [ £100 ] .

Can anybody suggest me how can we remove " Â " from excel-sheet output.

I am using following code for exporting functionaity:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
Dim objStringWriter As StringWriter = New StringWriter(sb)
Dim objHtmlTextWriter As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter)
gvBidTrackingExcel.DataSource = Getdata()
gvBidTrackingExcel.DataBind()
gvBidTrackingExcel.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter)
Response.Write(objStringWriter)
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a charset and encoding type after your Response.ContentType:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
```

**Otherwise:**

If this doesn't work try to set them as text field. Maybe they get rendered as float/doubles.

Here an example of an iteration which set a class to all cells before exporting (You have to customize my samples so they work for your solution)

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
{
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        }
    }
}
```

Add the style class to your document after rendering of your GridView

```
table.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; text-align:left; } </style> ";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue replacing £ with the unicode version, which is &#163; seemed to do the trick i.e.

```
myTempStr = Replace(myTempStr, "£", "&amp;#163;")
```